# How can I dynamically create HTML components in Marko?

Tags: dom, marko

I want to create new Marko components every time the user clicks a button — by calling something like the JavaScript DOM method `document.createElement("tag")`. How can I do this in Marko, not just with ordinary HTML tags, but with custom Marko tags?

What I tried: `document.createElement("custom-marko-component")`

Expected behavior: Marko engine compiles a new instance of the custom component.

Actual behavior: The browser makes a useless new `<custom-marko-component></custom-marko-component>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Marko's rendering functions (documentation: https://markojs.com/docs/rendering/):

Example:

```
// Create the custom component, like document.createElement() but asynchronous.
// Import `./custom-marko-component.marko`
var customComponent = require("./custom-marko-component"); 
var resultPromise = customComponent.render({});

// Insert the custom component into the webpage.
resultPromise.then(result => {
  result.appendTo(document.body);
});
```